# Can we connect Power BI with SSAS cubes deployed on sql server 2008

Tags: ssas, powerbi, ssas-2008

Can we connect Power BI with SSAS cubes, which are multidimensional and deployed on SQL Server 2008. I Have used power BI gateway, and power BI desktop, but it is only allowing me to connect multidimensional cubes which are deployed on 2012 or higher versions of SQL Server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I was able to add my multidimensional cubes on SSAS 2008 to power BI, and my cubes are getting refreshed to power BI on scheduled intervals. I had to upgrade MSOLAP 11.0 on the sql server to install power BI desktop, and we used power BI gateway to refresh cube data to Power BI. MSOLAP 11.0 is shipped with SQL Server 2012 or above but you can update this on the server with 2008 installed on it without upgrading SQL Server to 2012.

Answer (score 0):

That's correct. You need SQL 2012 SP1 CU4 or above and Enterprise edition to connect to a Multidimensional SSAS cube in Power BI currently.